# Every other Visual Studio "run test" attempt results in "Unable to start program QTAgent32.exe"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Whenever I run a test, and then try to run a test again, I get the following error:

> Failed to queue test run.
>
> Unable to start program 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe'.

If I run the test again after that, it proceeds as normal.  In other words, I get this error every other time I try to run a test.  It doesn't matter whether the previous test succeeded or failed, whether it ran to completion or was interrupted, or whether I run one test or all of them across the whole solution.

What could be causing this?  What can I try to fix it?

Comment: A quick search brought this up, no idea if it applies to you or not, but I thought I'd throw it out there.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lkruger/archive/2009/06/08/visual-studio-team-test-load-agent-goes-64-bit.aspx

Comment: Are you by any chance testing on a 64bit system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue at Microsoft, according [this Page](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/536475/launching-unit-tests-in-debugger-fails-every-other-time-cannot-start-qtagent32-exe) it happens on 64bit systems while testing with Visual Studio 2010. The page also describes a number of workarounds you can try.

Comment: Thanks for the link... for reference to others, here's a link to the [currently active item](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650038/launching-unit-tests-in-debugger-fails-every-other-time-when-a-project-started-life-as-wcf-application-related-to-536475) as well.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to solve this problem by turning off IntelliTrace.  Tools->Options->IntelliTrace, uncheck "Enable IntelliTrace".

Comment: While turning off IntelliTrace was a workaround that allowed us to debug/run our tests, we found out the real culprit later.  Our domain administrator had passed down new security rules which affected the permissions on certain folders.  Not sure the exact folder locations, but it made them inaccessible by the QTAgent32 process.  Our domain admin made some changes and suddenly we were back in business, running/debugging tests with full IntelliTrace support.