# Failed to queue test run ... QTAgent32.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

After freshly rebooting, I get the error in the title if I attempt to debug even the simplest, most trivial unit test.

[image]

It's the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104428/failed-to-queue-test-run-unable-to-start-the-agent-processvisual-studio-2010), but I don't see a good answer in there.

Any help anyone could provide would be appreciated immensely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Every other Visual Studio "run test" attempt results in "Unable to start program QTAgent32.exe"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307036/every-other-visual-studio-run-test-attempt-results-in-unable-to-start-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to solve this problem by turning off IntelliTrace. Tools->Options->IntelliTrace, uncheck "Enable IntelliTrace".

Comment: Instead of copy pasting the answer from another question. It's better to point the OP to that question instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug per [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307036/every-other-visual-studio-run-test-attempt-results-in-unable-to-start-program) and one of the work arounds  fixed it to me:

> It looks like Visual Studio insists building projects that started
>   their life as a WCFService Application. After removing the WCF Service
>   Application specific tags from the csproj xml files, unit tests work
>   every time. I removed the following tags: Under Property Group: Remove
>   ProjectTypeGuids and StartArguments Remove entire ProjectExtensions
>   node

FYI, to edit a project file first right click and unload the project. Then right click again and edit project file. The removed attributes shouldn't affect the running of the WCF service

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307036/every-other-visual-studio-run-test-attempt-results-in-unable-to-start-program)